# Show that an empirical mean converges uniformly to its expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

I have a statistic that can be written as the average of ergodic random variables identically distributed. This statistic depends on a parameter. It is known that the statistic converges in probability to the common expectation of the random variables. I am wondering if the convergence is uniform.

Here is the problem.

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a sequence of ergodic real-valued random variables identically distributed. Let $\theta \in \Theta$, where $\Theta$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I consider the statistic $S_n(\theta)$ defined by

$$S_n(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n f(X_i, \theta),$$ where $f$ is a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can I say that $S_n(\theta)$ uniformly converges to $S_0(\theta) = E(S_n(\theta))$?

I read somewhere that sufficient conditions for the uniform convergent are: $\Theta$ compact and $f$ bounded. But I am not very sure.

Comment: I think you misread, $S_n(\theta)$ is random, the best you can hope for is almost sure convergence (perhaps uniformly on sets with high probability, check Egoroff's theorem).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I double-checked. The author said that the convergence is almost sure and uniform. See this article https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0262.2007.00731.x in Econometrica. Uniform convergence on page 44. I don't know if I missed an assumption.
What do you mean by sets with high probability? $\theta$ is not random.

Comment: $\theta$ is not random but the $X_i$ are!

Comment: So what if the support of $X_i$ is bounded? I think that this condition is assumed too.